# Nullpointerexception in AWS Glue on dataframe_obj.count()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue-spark

Good day

I am writing a Glue job on AWS to transform data.  After doing a join on two sets of data (resulting in a dataframe of around 100MB in size), I get a Nullpointer exception when retrieving the count on the dataframe.  What makes this bug difficult to trace is that it only happens sporadically - occasionally it succeeds.

The error is:

```
21/05/07 08:27:08 ERROR ProcessLauncher: Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/transform.py", line 398, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/transform.py", line 355, in main
    extract_data(context, df1_trans, df2_trans)
  File "/tmp/transform.py", line 264, in extract_data
    joined_count = joined.count()
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 522, in count
    return int(self._jdf.count())
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o689.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 8795, 172.35.98.112, executor 5): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.open(EmrFileSystem.java:207)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.newStream(HadoopInputFile.java:65)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.initialize(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code in question:

```
    print("Applying join.")
    joined = (df1.join(df2, df1['ID'] == df2['ID'], how='inner')
              .select(df1["*"], df2["*"])
              .dropDuplicates(['ID', 'VAL']))
    extract_data joined_count = joined.count()    # Nullpointer exception here...
    print(f"Joined data: {joined_count}.") 
    write_out(context, joined, 'joined', "s3://<some_bucket>", "csv")

    # Retrieve data from joined data.
    tmp = (joined
           .withColumn('IDENT', joined['ID'])
           .withColumn('V1', joined['SOME_VALUE'])
           .withColumn('V2', joined['TIME'])
           .withColumn('V3', sf.lit('BLAH'))
           .withColumn('V4', sf.lit('3.14'))
           .select(['IDENT', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4']))
    tmp_count = tmp.count()
```

and the write out code:

```
def write_out(context, out, name, destination, destination_format):
    """
    Writes out the data as a single file.

    :param context:
    :param out:
    :param name:
    :param destination:
    :param destination_format:
    :return:
    """
    print(f"Writing {name} to {destination}.")

    glue_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(out.repartition(1), context)
    context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=glue_df,
        connection_type="s3",
        connection_options={"path": destination},
        format=destination_format)
```

...any assistance or just ideas on where to look would be helpful.

Comment: Your join looks a bit off, you are joining epg_df.id on df2.id, shouldn't it be df1.id?

Comment: I fixed it in the code, thank you.

Comment: Was that the problem?

Comment: I mean, I corrected the join code.  The Nullpointer exception still occurs.

Comment: Can you run `joined.show()` and `joined.printSchema()` ?

Comment: I ran it again, joined.show() and joined.printSchema() works and I get output (I replaced the count with the two commands), but now it breaks on the write_dynamic_frame inside the write_out method.  Also a NullpointerException.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232078/discussion-between-jaco-van-niekerk-and-robert-kossendey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone also runs into this.  It can happen the moment the data gets "collected".  So on writing out a partition of data, getting counts, etc.

The solution seems to be related to a Glue Dynamic Dataframe when loading the data.  Change to a Spark Dataframe and you're waxed.